# How to fill an 2D array with a 2D Smaller array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I apologize if this is not well explained. I am quite new to JavaScript.

I have a 2D arrayA that is 10x10 and a 2D arrayB that is 5x8. The smaller arrayB is populated with data and the larger arrayA is just populated with 0's by default.

How can i move the data from arrayB to arrayA while still leaving the leftover space of arrayA as 0's?

The end result must be that arrayA should contain all of the data in the same order as arrayB but with the leftover space still just containing 0's.

Comment: Please post some code and your attempt.

Comment: You want the B to be sort of "centered" inside A? Do I understand that correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I understood the question correctly, you can loop over each value of `arrayB` and assign it at the same indexes in `arrayA`:

```js
const arrayA = Array(10).fill(0).map(_ => Array(10).fill(0))
const arrayB = Array(5).fill(0).map(_ => Array(8).fill(1))

for (let y = 0; y < arrayB.length; y++) {
  for (let x = 0; x < arrayB[y].length; x++) {
    arrayA[y][x] = arrayB[y][x]
  }
}

console.log(arrayA.map(v => v.join(', ')).join('\n'))
```

The `console.log` is just for readability, to understand how the matrix looks.

Answer (score 0):

A simple `Array.map()` will do the job:

```js
const arrA = [
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
];

const arrB = [
 [0,1,2,3,4],
 [0,1,2,3,4],
 [0,1,2,3,4],
 [0,1,2,3,4],
 [0,1,2,3,4],
 [0,1,2,3,4],
 [0,1,2,3,4],
 [0,1,2,3,4],
];

const B2A = () => arrA.map(
  (val, index) => val.map(
    (subVal, subIndex) => {
      if(arrB[index] && arrB[index][subIndex]) return arrB[index][subIndex]
      return subVal;
    })
  )
  
console.log(B2A());
```

Comment: Thanks @Mose for adding arrays with data. I have used this in my answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `Array.from` and iterate, while iterate check if the value exists in filler array. If exists use that value otherwise same array value.

```js
const fill = (arr1, arr2) =>
  Array.from(arr1, (arr, row) =>
    Array.from(arr, (value, col) => (arr2[row] && arr2[row][col]) || value)
  );

const arrA = [
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
];

const arrB = [
  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
];

console.log(JSON.stringify(fill(arrA, arrB)));
```